# ARKit Unable to run the session, configuration is not supported on this device

Tags: ios, ios11, arkit

Using  ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration get and error on iPhone 6 plus
`Unable to run the session, configuration is not supported on this device`

What can it be?

Comment: ARKit doesn't support iphone 6 plus

Comment: this is indeed very strange because ARKit ran on a iPhone 6 plus but since the last update to a newer version of ios11 the support stopped ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is Apple's document for [ARKit and device support](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/)

> ARKit requires an iOS device with an A9 or later processor. To make
>   your app available only on devices supporting ARKit, use the arkit key
>   in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities section of your app's Info.plist.
>   If augmented reality is a secondary feature of your app, use the
>   isSupported property to determine whether the current device supports
>   the session configuration you want to use.

You can check ARKit support programatically at runtime using 'isSupported` property of ARConfiguration.

[ARConfiguration.isSupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported)

```
if (ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
    // ARKit is supported. You can work with ARKit
} else {
    // ARKit is not supported. You cannot work with ARKit
}
```

Following iOS devices (with iOS 11 installed) are supporting ARKit:

- iPhone X
- iPhone 8 and 8 Plus
- iPhone 6S and 6S Plus
- iPhone 7 and 7 Plus
- iPhone SE
- iPad Pro (9.7, 10.5 or 12.9)
- iPad (2017, 2018)

Here are some reference links related to ARKit Support & iOS device configurations:

ARKit runs on the Apple [A9 and A10](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/) & [A11 Bionic chip](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/) processors.

[iPhone Models - (Chip)](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)

[iPad Models - (Chip)](https://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/)

Comment: Yep iPad Pro works thanks! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uhQT02uS0fOG5NZ2Y5bE9tYzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Zaid Khan iPhone 6 is packed with Apples A8 Chip set. As per Apple Documentation ARKit Runs on the Apple A9, A10 and A11 chips only.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth Yes, But while I was having earlier iOS11 beta-5 ARKit was working in that.

Comment: @Zaid Khan there is no particular solution i found on your issue, may be apple can only answer this.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth Thanks, no worries.

Comment: that first link only leads to the ARKit landing page - nothing w/r to device support